# MongoDB aggregation vs editing fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am relatively new to database design, so please excuse me if what I am asking is elementary, but I don't really have anywhere to go to with this question.

​
Essentially, I have a soccer like game that stores data and statistics after every match, i.e Player 1: 2 goals 1 assist, Player 2: 0 goals 2 assists. I am creating a website to display this information, and my goal is to have unique player profiles, that show the players all time stats, essentially an aggregation of all a player's game stats.

I understand that mongoDB has the aggregate function to do this exact thing, my question is this efficient? I am worried that over time, because of the ever increasing amount of games, that the performance will take a hit, and the speed of page loads will follow. I expect an average of 50 games per day, so roughly over 18,000 documents every year. Is running an aggregate query the best idea for this project? Currently my database is set up that each player has a stats object, upon the conclusion of the game the players stats document is fetched, and the values are incremented based on the players stats in that game. This way there is no aggregation when displaying the values on the website, just searching for the players stats and displaying the values. Is this the better option? How should I organize this database so that my webpages wont take long to load, obviously I am not looking for lightning fast speeds, just want the option that best scales long term. My database schema is relatively simple, just a collection of players, games, and gamestats. What would the optimal structure for such a database?

Comment: load up a few hundred thousand records and see how long an aggregation takes.  No need to worry about optimizing if it already performs acceptably.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. Even on modest hardware, you should be able to run fast aggregate queries on millions of documents with no performance issues. There are many, many ways to optimize this once you get there (both within the db and outside the db). If it requires redesigning the db at that point to accommodate, that's fine, it's a good problem to have.